# DrawerLayout API : Does it work with API 8 and lower?

Tags: android, api, layout, drawerlayout

I am using the DrawerLayout from the support libs, and supposedly these API's from the library work for Android API 4+

For some reason, I can't get it working on API 8 (not sure about others) Works fine on Android 4.0++

Any Android API 8 isn't working (tested on many of my friends phone). Am I doing somethign wrong with DrawerLayout that won't make it work with API8?

**LOGCAT**

```
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:672)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:321)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  ... 29 more
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x0
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:327)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  ... 33 more
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml from xml type drawable resource ID #0x0
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1924)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1692)
08-30 02:50:36.753: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  ... 36 more
```

**XML file**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

**Main Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
     // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Settings home = new Settings();
    if (position == 0) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, home).commit();
    } else if (position == 1) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, home).commit();
    } else if (position == 2) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, home).commit();
    }

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}